Deriving Feynman rules for QED using the path integral
The Lagrangian for QED is
$$\mathcal{L} = \bar{\psi}(i\displaystyle{\not}\partial -m)\psi - \frac14(F_{\mu\nu})^2 - e\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi A_\mu = \mathcal{L}_0 - e\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi A_\mu.$$
I would like to derive the (position space) Feynman rules for this theory using the path integral approach. I am already familiar with how to do this for a scalar field theory, but the addition of multiple field types and multiple components in QED is giving me some trouble.
To keep it simple, suppose I would like to compute the following correlation function:
$$\langle\Omega\mid\mathcal{T}\big[\psi(x_1)\bar\psi(x_2)A_\mu(x_3)\big]\mid\Omega\rangle$$
which in the path integral looks like
$$\int\mathcal{D}\psi\mathcal{D}\bar\psi\mathcal{D}A_\mu \psi(x_1)\bar\psi(x_2)A_\mu(x_3) e^{iS_\textrm{QED}} = \int\mathcal{D}\psi\mathcal{D}\bar\psi\mathcal{D} A_\mu \psi(x_1)\bar\psi(x_2)A_\mu(x_3) e^{iS_0}e^{iS_\textrm{interaction}}$$
Expanding the second exponential in a power series we get
$$ \int\mathcal{D}\psi\mathcal{D}\bar\psi\mathcal{D} A_\mu \psi(x_1)\bar\psi(x_2)A_\mu(x_3) e^{iS_0} - ie\int d^4y\int\mathcal{D}\psi\mathcal{D}\bar\psi\mathcal{D} A_\mu \psi(x_1)\bar\psi(x_2)A_\mu(x_3) \bar\psi(y)\gamma^\mu \psi(y)A_\mu(y) e^{iS_0} + \mathcal{O}(e^2)\tag{1}$$
From (1) it is clear where the vertex rule for the Feynman diagram comes from. I would like to apply Wick's theorem to (1) to rewrite the path integrals as a sum of all possible contractions and two-point functions. However this would result in contractions containing, for example, $\psi$ and $A_\mu$ which we do not have a propagator for. This is where I am getting stuck. I have tried looking in many textbooks for this derivation, such as Peskin & Schroeder, but could not find a resource that goes through all the details.
Eventually I would like to relate the above to the vacuum of the free theory and bubble diagrams as is done for scalar fields, but I have omitted this for now.
My questions are:

In QED can we have any two-point functions other than $\langle \Omega \mid \psi(x) \bar\psi(y) \mid \Omega \rangle$ or $\langle \Omega \mid A_\mu(x) A_\nu(y) \mid \Omega \rangle$? I assume not, since we do not have propagators for objects such as $\langle \Omega \mid \psi(x) \psi(y) \mid \Omega \rangle$, $\langle \Omega \mid \bar\psi(x) \bar\psi(y) \mid \Omega \rangle$,  or $\langle \Omega \mid \psi(x) A_\mu(y) \mid \Omega \rangle$.
In view of Q1, how do we apply Wick's theorem to the path integrals in (1)? How do we deal with the contractions that mix field types?
Since we now have three path integrals instead of just one, what justifies the use of Wick's theorem?
Can we have any arbitrary number of $\psi$, $\bar\psi$, and $A_\mu$ fields in the correlation functions? Must there always be the same number of Dirac fields and their adjoints? Are there any restrictions on their spacetime location $x$?
How do we get the Feynman rules for the external lines and their polarizations from this approach?


Why the downvotes? How can I improve this question?

A fairly standard way to develop such amplitudes is to use generating functions. First one would add source terms for all the fields in the Lagrangian. Then one would pull all the interaction terms out of the integral by replacing the fields by functional derivatives with respect to the associated sources. With only the kinetic terms and sources terms left inside the integrals, one can evaluate all the integrals, thus producing exponential with the propagators dressed by the sources and a bunch of functional determinants that are independent of the sources. The functional derivatives now operate on the remaining exponential with the propagators producing all the Feynman diagrams. For correlators in fields, one just adds more functional derivatives. After having applied all the functional derivatives, one sets all the sources to zero. In this way one obtains all the Feynman diagrams.
From this procedure, one can read off all the Feynman rules. The vertex rule are those with the functional derivatives attached, and the propagators are those with the sources attached.
It is a rather quick explanation. Let me know if more detail (mathematical expressions) are necessary.

If you could add more detail and mathematical expressions that would be very helpful.
